# Nodejs - Simple socket.io example doesn't push data to all browers

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

It must have been some of my mistakes that I couldn't figure out how:

[client]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
    socket.on("message", function(data) {
        $("#theInput").val(data.data);
    });

    $(document).keyup(function() {
        socket.emit("message", {data: $("#theInput").val()});
    });
});
```

[server]

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    server = require("http").createServer(app);
    io = require("socket.io").listen(server),
    site = require("./site");

server.listen(8080);

app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");

app.use(express.logger("dev"));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

//Handling sockets
txt = "";
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("message", function(data) {
        txt = data.data;
        socket.emit("message", {data: txt});
    });
});
```

What I was trying to do is to send new data to server on the `$.keyup()` event, then the server should re-assign new input value into the global variable `txt`, and push that information back to the client. The client, on receiving any new data pushed from the server, should change the value of `#theInput`. It's kinda like opening 2 browsers, and type in 1, it should appears on another browser as well. It works well if I open only 1 browser, which means it receives data and re-assign to the `#theInput`, but when I open 2 different tabs/browsers to test its synchronization, whenever the `keyup` event fires, it replaces the global `txt` in server, and I didn't see any synchronization or real time in those browsers.

I'm fairly new and would appreciate much any help or hints to solve the problem.

**Additional question**: In index.jade (just imagine I have one), like in this structure:

```
root
|____ views
|    |_____ index.jade
|
|____ libs
|    |_____ jQuery.js
|
|server.js
```

From jade, I tried to:

```
script(src="./libs/jQuery.js")
```

But it results in 404, Not found. I suddenly remember that I need to route every request, so maybe I should do the same with external library, so I go:

[server.js]

```
site = require("./site");
app.get("/jQuery", site.jQuery);
```

And define route:

[site.js]

```
exports.jQuery = function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile("./libs/js/jQuery.js");
};
```

The file is then found, but an error occurs:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

What is jQuery.min.map even is? I've never encountered anything like this. I searched through the Internet for all express example, but unfortunately, they all use shortcuts `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js` to embed jQuery. That works and is my temporary solution. So is there anyway to embed jQuery relatively like traditional server would do?

Comment: If you are sending data to all clients then you should use broadcast. Check here for example - http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: I've read that, and my script quite follows the example. Like, using `socket.on`, `socket.emit`... All are extracted from the example. I don't know where did I do wrong. Could you please take a look and help me out?

Comment: In your server, instead of `socket.emit("message", {data: txt});` try `io.sockets.emit("message", {data: txt});`

Comment: The following error appears if I edited `socket.emit` to `io.socket.emit`: Cannot call method `emit` of undefined.

Comment: it's `io.sockets.emit`

Comment: IT WORKS! Can you please explain what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server program change `socket.emit` to `io.sockets.emit`.

`socket.emit` will send message to specific socket (client) that got connected. `io.sockets.emit` will send message to all connected sockets (clients)